# Getting checkboxes to maintain checked state on click

Tags: jquery

I've tried various methods to get my checkboxes to be checked upon a click.

The following works on document ready:

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr("checked","checked");
```

However as soon as I surround it with a click event the checkboxes won't maintain checked state. On the click they check (as they should) and then immediately uncheck.

```
$("#selectall").click(function(){
$('input[name=foo]').attr("checked","checked");
});
```

My HTML:

```
<form id="frm1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Checkboxes don't need scripting to work - they do all that automatically.

Comment: Can you show this in a fiddle ?

Comment: There's clearly a `#selectall` element to check all given checkboxes, plus the keyword **maintain** checked status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use...

```
[type=checkbox]    

$("#selectall").click( function(){ $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked","checked"); } );
```

Comment: Oh I just tried your fiddle and it worked. It seems it was the href in my link that was causing the problem. Removing that worked. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Oh I see, because it kept reloading the page huh? x)

Comment: Yes VIDesignz. You answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

**HTML**

```
<input id="selectall" type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar">Select ALL

    <form id="form1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" />
       <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" /> 
       <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" /> 
       <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" />
    </form>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#selectall").click(function() {
    $('#form1 input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/z4B2U/4/)**

Comment: VIDesignz .. Was lazy to create the HTML ;)